# Usage of "us all"

Tags: phrase-usage

> This story has a useful lesson for us all

In this sentence, need to know the use of us all...

Comment: ***Us all*** is an informal (and mostly regional) way of saying ***all of us***.

Comment: @JasonBassford to my ear, "us all" is more formal than "all of us."  It certainly seems to be older.

Comment: I'd say "us all" is neutral, no more formal or informal than "we all".

Comment: I think "all of us" is slightly more emphatic about it applying to everybody than "us all" is, but there's not a great difference.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, “us all” means something like “everyone”.

“A lesson for us” could also work, but “us all” 
makes it very clear that it is a lesson for, literally, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

"Us all" and "you all" are ways of emphasizing the totality of a group, much like "all of us/you". "Us all" does not sound particularly formal or informal to my ears. A notable use is in the song ["Honor to Us All"](https://youtu.be/O2QJ5n1uQWU?t=16) (Disney's *Mulan*).

Answer (score 0):

[To quote Cambridge:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/all)

> When "all" refers to a personal pronoun which is the object in a clause, we can use pronoun + "all" or "all of" + pronoun. The pronoun is in the object form:
>
> I used to have three pens but I’ve lost *them all.* (or: but I’ve lost *all of them*).
>
> **Not:** but I lost *all them.*